# How to add computed data to API response of Vue-Apollo

Tags: javascript, vue.js, apollo-client, vue-apollo

I have a page with Schedules and correspond components.
Here is my Single File Components structure:

```
├─ ScheduleList
├─── ScheduleItem
└────── SubSchedule
```

I get an array of schedules from API with $apollo: smth like that:

```js
export default {
  ...
  apollo: {
    scheduleItems: {
      query: ALL_SCHEDULE_ITEMS
       ...
}
```

Data model of schedules look like

```
ScheduleItem {
  id: Int
  orderNumber: Int
  subSchedules: SubSchedule[]
  ...
}

SubScheduleItem {
    id: Int
    orderNumberInSchedule: Int
    schedule_id: Int // parent id
    duration: Int // in seconds
    ...
}
```

I want to add a computed property `start_time` to apollo's response object of each `subSchedule` and correspond `schedule`. In another words: I want to add a computed property on API layer of frontend application.

Expected response with computed prop:

```json
[
  {
    id: 1,
    orderNumber: 1,
    subSchedules: [ { ..., duration: 100, ... } ],
    start_time: 0
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    orderNumber: 2,
    subSchedules: [ { ..., duration: 200, ... } ],
    start_time: 100
  }
]
```

Let's abstract now from time format and imagine that:

- Start time of first `subSchedule` is `0`.
- time represents always in seconds, where `0` is first second of the day/event/etc.

How I could get it work?

I did it before with computed getters in Vuex ORM as I worked with REST APIs, but apollo suggest to avoid using Vuex because that apollo is Application State Management replacement.

I'm using Vue 2 with JavaScript.